# Outlook add-in - convert inline images into base64 and replace the image in the body

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, email-attachments, outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook add-in which takes the body of an email finds the inline images gets the base64 encoding and then replaces the src of the inline image to base64 version, this is then sent to an api and the body is saved in a db.

I am doing this by getting the all the Attachments using getAttachmentsAsync() then getting all the images in the email body then matching the names of the images with the attachment names.

I have noticed that some inline images on Outlook desktop app show like the below and the getAttachmentsAsync method does not return the cid so there is no way to match them

```
<img contenttype="image/png" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:4f9c247a-820d-4ec2-ade3-1bc8783b067c" style="max-width: 1436px;" size="3027"/>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how i can achieve  this or another way of doing/dealing with this ?

Thanks,
Ritesh

**MORE INFORMATION**

This is not happening for every inline/embeded image only for some

This is the image src

```
Image src = cid:9CD03B115934420393C4E38F215995CC
```

When I call `getAttachmentsAsync()` this is returned, nothing matches the `cid` of the image

[getAttachmentsAsync output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uDYV.png)

Comment: Does your mail item have any attachments with such name like stated for the `cid` attribute?

Comment: Yes the code above is one of the inline images (attachmenst) from my email the src is src="cid:4f9c247a-820d-4ec2-ade3-1bc8783b067c"

Comment: Then you need to search for the attachment name specified in the `cid` attribute when you can't find the a corresponding property set on the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property set on the attachment you need to search for the attachment name specified for the `cid` attribute .

Comment: Please see the more information I have added above there is no way to match the image, any ideas? Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at the Outlook internals using any low-level MAPI tools such as MFCMAPI to make sure the item has the properties set unlike produced by OfficeJS?